# Pinning Group Policy Editor to Start In Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, start-menu

Is it possible to pin "Group Policy Editor" to start menu in windows 10? If yes, could you describe how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the **Local Group Policy Editor**?  If so, do the following:

1. Right-click on your desktop and select `New` > `Shortcut`
2. When asked to type the location of the item, enter `%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\gpedit.msc`

   [image: Shortcut Location]
3. When asked to type a name for the shortcut, enter `Local Group Policy Editor`

   [image: Shortcut Name]
4. After the new shortcut appears on your desktop, right-click it and select `Pin to Start`

   [image: Pin to Start]

When you utilize it, ensure that you have full admin privileges by right-clicking the Start Menu item, selecting `More`, and then choosing `Run as administrator`.

[image: Run as administrator]